# Layout part in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I have a standard layout across my project, but for one module I have a secondary navigation bar.  What is the best way for me to include this into the project, without having to create the navigation bar in each of my action.phtml files?

Ideally I would have my standard layout.phtml and then in the module have the nav.phtml and my action.phtml files, but how do I get that to work?

Comment: The partial view helper: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html perhaps? Or maybe a custom one. You can also just render standalone templates.

Comment: Perhaps you can be inspired by the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217573/zf3-multiple-modules-and-multiple-layouts/48229306#48229306